# Can we know the fingerprint id of touched fingerprint

Tags: android

I have 5 fingerprints on my phone. Can I detect which finger's fingerprint is touched when the user touch with any of the fingerprints on the device.
I tried this with
 `FingerprintManager` 
but I failed.

Comment: No, Android's fingerprint API doesn't support this. Any fingerprint enrolled on the device can be used to complete a fingerprint authentication, and you only get to know whether or not the authentication succeeded.

Comment: Note that there is a `getFingerprint` method in the `AuthenticationResult` class. However, it is marked `@hide` and app developers are strongly discouraged from using it, so continue with that approach at your own risk.

Comment: @Michael I need this for my Personal App. It will not be shared, it will be only on my phone so do you recommend me to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. you can authorize stored fingerprint using system. but you cant get any id from fingerprint reader.

let me explain why...

This is how finger print scanner store data.

[image]
ARM TrustZone is used to keep biometric and cryptographic data secure. ARM processors can keep this information securely on the physical chip using its Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) based TrustZone technology. This secure area is also used for other cryptographic processes and to communicate directly with secure hardware platforms, such as a fingerprint scanner, to prevent any software snooping. Approved pieces of none personal information, such as a password key, can only be accessed by applications using the TEE client APIs.

A TEE is a separate and isolated area in the phone's hardware. A TEE might use its own processor and memory or it can use a virtualized instance on the main CPU. In both cases, the TEE is fully isolated and insulated using hardware-backed memory and input/output protection. The only way you will be getting in is if the TEE lets you in, and it never will. Even if the phone is rooted or the bootloader unlocked, the TEE is separate and still intact.

this is how finger print login works
[image]

source - https://www.androidauthority.com/how-fingerprint-scanners-work-670934/
https://www.androidcentral.com/how-does-android-save-your-fingerprints